# Indexes on fields with low amount of possible values

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a table consisting of millions of records,for which I will be doing selects with a Where on both `FieldA` and `FieldB`. FieldA has thousands of possible values, whilst FieldB only has 5. Would I be best off:

1. adding index on each record i.e Index(A), Index(B)
2. adding index on only FieldA
3. adding a grouped index i.e. Index(A,B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you of use a composite index  on both the field

```
 index my_index_name on my_table(fieldA, fieldB)
```

The use of fieldA or FieldB in firts position don'yt should change the performance in a particolare way ..,but the most selectable for firts is preferred

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing `WHERE A=(constant) AND B=(constant)`, then `INDEX(A,B)` and `INDEX(B,A)` work equally well.

But...  `OR` messes things up.  `<` messes things up.  `IN` messes things up.  Etc, etc.

Short rule for building the "best" index for `WHERE ... AND ...`

1. Gather up any columns with `= (constant)` *first*.
2. Then you can add *one* more column involved in a range, etc.

Example:  `WHERE A < 123 AND B = 987` can benefit most from `INDEX(B, A)` *in that order*.

If you have `WHERE A=333` in one query and `WHERE B=777` in another (nothing AND'd), then you need *two* indexes, one `(A)` (or *beginning* with `A`), and a similar one for B.  `INDEX(B, A)` will *not* work for both.

[*More tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Comment: Excellent input thank you. I never quite understood when to do Index(A,B) vs Index(A), Index(B) but it seems from your reply that the basic rule is 1) A and B need to be used in the same query and 2) put the one with the constant first.